# Cannot run simple WHERE query in node-postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, node-postgres

This is my table:

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE "Friendships" (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"Friendships_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "fromUserId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Users"(id),
    "toUserId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Users"(id)
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Friendships_pkey" ON "Friendships"(id int4_ops);
```

This is my query:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const pgClient = new Client({ user: PG_USERNAME, host: PG_HOST, database: PG_DB, password: PG_PASSWORD, port: 5432 })
pgClient.connect()

pgClient.query({
            name: 'fetch-friendships',
            text: 'SELECT * FROM Friendships WHERE fromUserId = $1',
            values: [1]
        }, (err, res) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(res)
        })
```

Error: `relation "friendships" does not exist`

```
cosmos=> \dt;
            List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  | Owner 
--------+-----------------+-------+-------
 public | AuthCodes       | table | pangu
 public | BirthRecords    | table | pangu
 public | Births          | table | pangu
 public | Friendships     | table | pangu
 public | InvitationCodes | table | pangu
 public | SequelizeMeta   | table | pangu
 public | Users           | table | pangu
(7 rows)

cosmos=> SELECT * FROM Friendships;
ERROR:  relation "friendships" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM Friendships;
```

Comment: Are you logged into the correct database schema?

Comment: @GMB, see edits

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM "Friendships"`. In Oracle, if you double quote a table or column name during creation, you are making it case-sensitive. But that would force you tom make case-sensitive queries as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres you need use double quotes if create the table with upper cases.

Without double quotes

```
Friendships -> friendships
```

As you can see for the error:

> ERROR:  relation "friendships" does not exist

but you create

```
CREATE TABLE "Friendships" (
```

So you need use `"Friendships"`

Same goes for Tables, Field names or Function names.

Comment: Thanks! How can I use AS alias in my query? `SELECT * FROM "Friendships" AS "F" where "F.fromUserId" = 1` throws error: ` Perhaps you meant to reference the column "f.fromUserId".`

Comment: You need use `"F"."fromUserId" ` double quote every item, table, alias or field

Comment: my suggestion use dash and lower case to avoid use double quotes. so use `friendship` and `from_user_id` instead